# Python Beautiful Soup: get text from element

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am looping through elements of type `<td>` but am struggling to extract the `<td>` text.

HTML:

```
<td class="cell">
 Brand Name 1
 <br/>
 (
 <a class="tip" title="This title">
  Authorised Resellers
 </a>
 )
</td>
```

: Desired output:

```
Brand name: Brand name 1
Brand distribution type: Authorised Reseller
```

I have tried:

```
for brand in brand_loop:
  print(brand.text)
```

But this does not print the text following the opening `<td>` tag ("Brand Name 1").

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
for brand in brand_loop:
  print(brand.text)
  print(brand.find('a').text)
```

You can only print the text of the selected element directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can select `<td class="cell">` and then `.find_next(text=True)` to get brand name, and then `.find_next('a')` to get brand distribution type.

For example:

```
txt = '''<td class="cell">
 Brand Name 1
 <br/>
 (
 <a class="tip" title="This title">
  Authorised Resellers
 </a>
 )
</td>'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

brand_name = soup.select_one('td.cell').find_next(text=True)
bran_distribution = brand_name.find_next('a').text

print('Brand name:', brand_name.strip())
print('Brand distribution type:', bran_distribution.strip())
```

Prints:

```
Brand name: Brand Name 1
Brand distribution type: Authorised Resellers
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find()` and `next_element` to get first `td` tag text.And to get `a` tag text simple use `find()`. You can try it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_doc = '''<td class="cell">
 Brand Name 1
 <br/>
 (
 <a class="tip" title="This title">
  Authorised Resellers
 </a>
 )
</td>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc,'lxml')
brand_name = soup.find("td").next_element.strip()
brand_distribution_type = soup.find("a").text.strip()
print('Brand name:', brand_name)
print('Brand distribution type:', brand_distribution_type)
```

Output will be:

```
Brand name: Brand Name 1
Brand distribution type: Authorised Resellers
```